# Unable to find project.json

Tags: asp.net-core

I did some updates to my project in VS 2015 update 3 and now I have this error :

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to find project.json in 'C:\Users\Julius\Documents\Projects\School\Development\In Progress\ReportBook\ReportBook.Auth'   ReportBook.Auth     1`

The following is my project.json file with the new updates. Just not sure if the framework section is at the right place. In any case that is where it has been all this while.

```
{
    "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true,
        "preserveCompilationContext": true
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection": "1.0.0-alpha2-final",
        "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation": "1.0.0-alpha2-final",
        "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
            "type": "build",
            "version": "1.1.0"
        },
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq": "1.0.3.3",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
            "version": "1.1.0",
            "type": "platform"
        },
        "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.1.0",
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
        "ReportBook.Data": "1.0.0-*",
        "ReportBook.Repository": "1.0.0-*",
        "ReportBook.Service": "1.0.0-*",
        "Repository.Pattern.EFCore": "1.0.0-*",
        "SimpleIdentityServer.Authentication.Common": "1.0.0",
        "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates": "4.3.0"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "imports": [
                "dotnet5.6",
                "portable-net45+win8"
            ]
        }
    },
    "publishOptions": {
        "include": [
            "wwwroot",
            "**/*.cshtml",
            "appsettings.json",
            "web.config"
        ]
    },
    "runtimeOptions": {
        "configProperties": {
            "System.GC.Server": true
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "postpublish": ["dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath%   --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"]
    },
    "tools": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
    }
}
```

This was working previously till i did the updates,

Comment: Is the `project.json` file actually there?

Comment: YEah it is and here is an additional error that just came up 'C:\Users\Julius\Documents\Projects\School\Development\In Progress\ReportBook\ReportBook.Auth\project.json' does not have any frameworks listed in the 'frameworks' section. but I do have that section in there "frameworks": {

    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

Comment: Did you try to run `dotnet restore` CLI command? If that is also giving same error then share your `dotnet --version` and `global.json`

Comment: Yeah I did that. >dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview2-1-003177. I dont have global.json

Comment: This is the message I get when I run dotnet restore:  Error reading 'C:\Users\Julius\Documents\Projects\School\Development\In Progress\ReportBook\ReportBook.Auth\project.json' at line 7 column 19 : Package dependencies must specify a version range.
error:   Package dependencies must specify a version range.

Comment: Ok, here is an observation I just made regarding the the last error message I just posted. It appears the dotnet coomand expects to see a version number after every colon e.g.  "IdentityServer4": "1.0.0". So it finds  "buildOptions": {
      "emitEntryPoint": true,
      "preserveCompilationContext": true
    }, and complains about verion number. What is baffling me is that I have two similar projects in the same solution and they are not complaining.

Comment: I think I may have found the solution, Looks entries like "builderOptions" where placed at the wrong location. I followed the arrangement in my other projects and now things are running smoothly